PG17 functions used in materialized views not using index when search_path is set
The first incompatibility note for PG17 notes:

Functions used by expression indexes and materialized views that need to reference non-default schemas must specify a search path during function creation.

Re-creating materialized views (that worked fine in PG 14-16) using functions that depend on the ltree extension installed to public fails on PG17 with:
ERROR:  operator does not exist: public.ltree <@ public.ltree
LINE 3:   code_b <@ code_a

CONTEXT:  SQL function "myfunc" during inlining

If I add set search_path = public to the function definition as suggested by the incompatibility notes, the materialized view can be created.
But once set search_path is added, the function is no longer usable - the planner doesn't pick up indexes on the ltree types.
Is there a workaround to get functions used in a materialized view to pick up the ltree operators in public?  Or to nudge the planner to use the indexes? Or am I doing something wrong?
To reproduce, on a fresh PG 17.0 database (and much the same on dockerized PostgreSQL 17.1 (Debian 17.1-1.pgdg110+1)):
select version();
                                                           version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 17.0 (Homebrew) on aarch64-apple-darwin24.1.0, compiled by Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4), 64-bit

-- check the default search path
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path';
     setting
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)


-- setup test data
create extension if not exists ltree;

create schema test;

create table test.table
(id serial primary key,
 code ltree);

insert into test.table (code)
select
  concat_ws('.',
    rpad(trunc(random() * 10 + 1)::text, 3, '0'),
    rpad(trunc(random() * 10 + 1)::text, 3, '0'),
    rpad(trunc(random() * 100 + 1)::text, 3, '0'),
    rpad(trunc(random() * 100 + 1)::text, 3, '0'),
    rpad(trunc(random() * 100 + 1)::text, 3, '0')
)::ltree as code
from generate_series(1, 1000000) s(i);

create index on test.table using gist (code);
create index on test.table using btree (code);

-- create test function as per pg16 (no search path)
create or replace function test.myfunc(
  code_a ltree,
  code_b ltree)
RETURNS boolean language sql AS $$
SELECT
  code_b <@ code_a
$$
immutable parallel safe;

-- test the function - it picks up the index
explain analyze
select
  a.id
from test.table a
inner join (select * from test.table limit 10) as b
on test.myfunc(a.code, b.code);
                                                               QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..15541.90 rows=100000 width=4) (actual time=0.105..1.078 rows=11 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=36) (actual time=0.015..0.019 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on "table"  (cost=0.00..20310.00 rows=1000000 width=36) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using table_code_idx on "table" a  (cost=0.41..1454.16 rows=10000 width=36) (actual time=0.086..0.104 rows=1 loops=10)
         Index Cond: (code @> "table".code)
 Planning Time: 1.475 ms
 Execution Time: 1.175 ms
(7 rows)

-- try and use the function in a materialized view,
-- (works fine in PG14,PG16, fails on PG17)
create materialized view test.myview as
select
  a.id
from test.table a
inner join (select * from test.table limit 10) as b
on test.myfunc(a.code, b.code);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: public.ltree <@ public.ltree
LINE 3:   code_b <@ code_a
                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:
SELECT
  code_b <@ code_a

CONTEXT:  SQL function "myfunc" during inlining

-- try specifying search_path as recommended in
-- PG17 release notes
create or replace function test.myfunc(
  code_a ltree,
  code_b ltree)
RETURNS boolean set search_path = public language sql AS $$
SELECT
  code_b <@ code_a
$$
immutable parallel safe;

-- test the new function - it works, but does not pick up the index
explain analyze
select
  a.id
from test.table a
inner join (select * from test.table limit 10) as b
on test.myfunc(a.code, b.code);
                                                             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2645310.33 rows=3333333 width=4) (actual time=0.335..6668.876 rows=11 loops=1)
   Join Filter: test.myfunc(a.code, b.code)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 9999989
   ->  Seq Scan on "table" a  (cost=0.00..20310.00 rows=1000000 width=36) (actual time=0.034..46.823 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.35 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=10 loops=1000000)
         ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=0.00..0.30 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=0.008..0.012 rows=10 loops=1)
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.011 rows=10 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on "table"  (cost=0.00..20310.00 rows=1000000 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=10 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.313 ms
 Execution Time: 6668.912 ms
(10 rows)

-- Try using the updated func in materialized view
-- The view is successfully created (on this small sample), 
-- but is impractical on larger data because it doesn't use the index
create materialized view test.myview as
select
  a.id
from test.table a
inner join (select * from test.table limit 10) as b
on test.myfunc(a.code, b.code);
SELECT 11


A condition like test.myfunc(a.code, b.code) cannot use an index. In your first example, an index is used, because the function is inlined: it is replaced by its definition, and that expression can use the index.
If you set the search_path on the function, it can no longer be inlined. That's why that example cannot use an index.
I recommend that you don't use the function, but define the materialized view using the operator directly.

Thanks, that inlining reference is exactly what I was missing. The function hides a lot of complexity - I might have to create/refresh tables instead of using materialized views.
